# Dynamic UIWebView <UIWebViewDelegate> methods aren't being called even though the delegate is set and is being logged

Tags: xcode5, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm calling a `UIView` (creating it and adding it to the stack) dynamically from an `NSObject` class that handles the "collecting of data" from various sources to the `UIViewController` for the `UIView` I just created. The `UiViewController` takes the data (which is returned as `HTML` and `CSS`) and assigns it to the `UIWebview` - and all this works fine, and looks great.

The whole point of all this, is to send the webpage to a printer. But the print methods aren't being triggered in the `UIViewController` above, because they are in the `UIWebViewDelegate` methods. I have to wait for it to load:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
DLog(@"WEB VIEW LOADED!!");

if ([[self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.readyState"] isEqualToString:@"complete"]) {

    UIImage *image = [self imageFromWebview:self.webview];

    DLog(@"FINISHED!!");
    for (NSDictionary *printer in self.existingPrinters) {
        //Print here
        }
    }


}
}
```

This is what I've done that hasn't worked:
( I have `<UIWebViewDelegate>` in the .h file `webview` is a synthesized strong (I also tried retain), nonatomic property)

The first thing I tried was to assign the delegate to the webview in the `viewWillAppear` method then I subsequently tried `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLoad`; setting the delegate like so `self.webview.delegate = self;` and (I also tried) `[self.webview setDelegate:self];`

Then I tried making a `.xib` file and calling the view that way; attaching a web view to `files owner` and setting the delegate in the builder.

```
WebViewPrintViewController *printerController = (WebViewPrintViewController *)[[WebViewPrintViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebViewPrintViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

I've even tried to set the delegate from the `NSObject` class:

```
[webPrintVC.webview setDelegate:webPrintVC];
```

I then tried to use the `StoryBoard` calling  the view "the long way:"

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
WebViewPrintViewController *myVC = (WebViewPrintViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewPrintController"];
```

...each time the view gets called, yet the webview delegate methods don't!

I've even tried adding `sleep(2);` to various methods to see if I could force the View to wait for the viewController on another thread, using various `dispatch_async`/ main thread combinations...

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

DLog(@"VIEW DID APPEAR!");
    //self.webview.frame = CGRectMake(self.webview.frame.origin.x, self.webview.frame.origin.y-self.webview.frame.size.height-25, self.webview.frame.size.width, self.webview.frame.size.height);
self.webview.delegate = self;
[self.view setNeedsDisplay]; //another desperate attempt to evoke the delegate methods

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:YES];

self.webview.delegate = self;

[self.webview loadHTMLString:HTML baseURL: nil];
[self.view addSubview:self.webview];

DLog(@"VIEW WILL APPEAR!");

}
```

Also when i use the `.xib` file the delegate is set, as evident by this `Dlog` statement:

```
DLog(@"WEBVIEWCONTROLLER LOADED!!! WHATS THE DELEGATE OF THE WEB VIEW : %@ THIS IS SELF : %@", self.webview.delegate, self);
```

This is the result:

```
2014-07-11 08:32:21.708 pos[14292:60b] -[WebViewPrintViewController viewDidLoad] [Line 54] WEBVIEWCONTROLLER LOADED!!! WHATS THE DELEGATE OF THE WEB VIEW : <WebViewPrintViewController: 0xc202c0> THIS IS SELF : <WebViewPrintViewController: 0xc202c0>
```

I'm at a loss...can anyone help?

I need to get the `UIWebViewDelegate` methods working. Thank you!

Keith

Comment: Maybe the webView finishes loading before the delegate is set? Try testing with a delegate method that you can manually trigger, so that you can rule out timing issues. Specifically, `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` gets called whenever you try to navigate to another URL in the webView. If you click a link and that method doesn't get called, then I'd guess you probably either implemented the method in the wrong class (should be in WebViewPrintController) or the WebViewPrintController is no longer set as the delegate at the time that you clicked the link.

Comment: @eyuelt Thanks. I figured that I was calling the web view from a second nested thread, and when i called it from the "correct thread" the delegate methods fired. For example i was instantiating the web view from a sub class which was already running in the background. I called it from the parent class, and all was good. For some reason then the main_quque was recognized; i made due.

Comment: Ok cool. You're not adding the webView to the screen on the background queue though, are you? Remember that UI should only be done on the main queue.

Comment: @eyuelt No in the main queue ...I wrap it in a main queue.

Comment: @eyuelt any clue on this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264465/delegating-webviews-in-xcode